# How to write gzipped JSON in overwrite mode in Spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe and want to write it to a specific output directory while overwriting existing output and compress it using gzip. I succeed in getting either gzip or the overwrite behavior, but not both.

For writing gzipped data this works:

```
df.toJSON() \
  .saveAsTextFile(output_path, compressionCodecClass='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec')
```

For doing the overwrite this works:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').json(output_path)
```

Looking at the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save) it seems you can pass options to the save method, but every variant I've tried doesn't work.